# Cannot get grid splitter to work the way I would like within 3 column grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridsplitter

I have the following grid using WPF and a few third party controls (Telerik):

```
<Grid x:Name="grid2" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth='80'/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="26"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <telerik:RadBreadcrumb Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Header="RadBreadcrumb"/>
            <telerik:RadTreeView Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="5" Height="auto"/>
        <telerik:RadTransitionControl x:Name="Trans" Grid.Column="2" Width="auto"/>
    </Grid>
```

Currently I am trying to make it so that the grid in column 0 (on the left side) will not re-size while re-sizing the window. I was able to achieve this effect by setting the width of column "0" to either a static 150 or auto. However, when I did this, the grid splitter no longer respected the minimum width of column 2 and allowed it to drag off the screen. By setting both column 0 and 2 to a width of star (the way I have it in the code now) the min widths are respected (the columns can't shrink past the 150 and 80 defined) but they don't re-size properly (the left column re-sizes in proportion to the right column). I would like to somehow get both the resize and the gridsplitter to work at the same time. Let me know if I wasn't clear enough or if more input is needed.

Comment: I just tried loading and running your Xaml and it seems to work fine when the telerik controls are replaced with dock panels.  What does it mean '...both the resize and gridsplitter to work at the same time?  Or is this a telerik specific question?

Comment: I would try pulling the RowDefinitions up directly into the grid.  And with a splitter you typically would not set a width of auto.

Comment: @GarryVass, I have no reason to believe it is a Telerik specific issue, and by the re-size and gridsplitter to work at the same time I mean that I wish the the two issues that I'm having to be resolved with the same piece of code. I want when I re-size the window the left column's width to not re-size as well as when I drag the gridsplitter to the far edges it stops when I hit my MinWidth's of either column. Currently I can do both of these, but not with the same piece of code.

Comment: @Blam I'm not sure what you exactly mean by pulling the RowDefinitions up, and I'm actually not setting the splitter width to auto and never suggested such. Just to be clear, column 0 is the left, column 1 is the gridsplitter, and column 2 is the right side.

Comment: @BrandonGodfrey, on the window resize requirement, does it mean that the left grid must persist the same ACTUAL WIDTH?  Or just the same proportionate width to the client area?

Comment: @GarryVass I would like it to persist the same actual width. The proportionate width is achieved with * which I do not want.

Comment: You are going to have to place an attached behaviour on the window (lucky you!), OR use value converter.  Or alternatively, hook in to the Grid's MeasureOverride method (lucky you again!).  Those are the only 3 options I can think of and none of them are totally attractive.

Comment: @GarryVass Alright, I'll give that a try I suppose, thanks very much for your help and time.

Comment: @Blam, what happened to yours?  Was something offensive?

Comment: @GarryVass Umm, I think he may have removed it himself after I had disagreed with him :(

Comment: Pulled my answer because OP did not improve the question based on my input.  Yes OP disagreed (based on ignorant speculation there was an XAML based solution).  Until OP can post an XAML based answer OP is wrong.

Comment: @Blam, thanks for answering.  I agree that the way the question is framed, there's no Xaml solution.  It's an attached behaviour and at best awkward to implement.  Impossible to test.

Comment: @Blam I suppose I may be wrong and thus apologize for posting such a poor question. This is my first time on stack overflow and I'm still very new to WPF and I'm still on its learning curve. If I ever do find a solution I'll be sure to post it. All the same, thanks for your time and help.

Comment: @GarryVass I suppose I may be wrong and thus apologize for posting such a poor question. This is my first time on stack overflow and I'm still very new to WPF and I'm still on its learning curve. If I ever do find a solution I'll be sure to post it. All the same, thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Yes it is a poorly worded question and you still have done nothing to fix it. Many people will not have the telerik so they cannot reproduce the problem.  Post the simplest conditions that reproduce the problem.   When some offers feedback don't tell them they are wrong unless you know they are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So, this isn't exactly what I was looking for, but it's doing the job for me:

```
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MinWidth="150" MaxWidth="1000"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I set the MaxWidth of my left hand column so that you could no longer drag the splitter past the point of no return on the right side. This solution also allows me to set the first column's width to auto (which makes the re-sizing work the way I intended as well). Unless you have a monitor smaller than 1000px wide (which in the environment I'm working in won't happen) this solution will work just using XAML. Again, I'm a little disappointed with this solution but its at least working in a simplistic manner.

Comment: this solves a different problem.  And it's in a different domain than the one you originally posted.  But all's well that ends well...